# MySQL close the number sequence gap or suggest new sequence element

Tags: mysql, sql, counter

My table looks like that:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Room` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupied_hours` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `number` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Number here is like counter in combination with 2 more values: `branch_id`, `course_id`. So for example if table looks like that:

```
... | branch_id | course_id | number | ...
        1             1           1
        1             1           3
```

what I want to do is, when I insert to this table to fill either gap between number fields (in this case 2) or give the +1 number of maximum (if gap doesn't exist) like 4 in this case if there was 2 value also.

It'd be great if there was a way to create it as procedure. Not long sql. How can I achieve this? Any ready to go function?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` should do

```
SELECT Coalesce(Min(number),1) AS number, branch_id, course_id
FROM
  (SELECT r1.number -1 AS number, r1.branch_id, r1.course_id
  FROM `Room` AS r1
  LEFT JOIN `Room` AS r2
    ON r1.branch_id = r2.branch_id 
      AND r1.course_id = r2.course_id
      AND (r1.number - 1) = r2.number
  WHERE r1.number > 1 AND r2.number IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Max(number) + 1, branch_id, course_id
  FROM `Room`
  GROUP BY branch_id, course_id) AS q
GROUP BY branch_id, course_id
```

Comment: It gives error. `'SELECT (r1.number-1) AS number, r1.branch_id, r1.course_id
  FROM `Room` AS r1
 ' at line 2`

Comment: @demonoid Oh, I forgot about `FROM`

Comment: What it returns? I don't understand

Comment: @demonoid it should return the gap/next number. Haven't actually tested it though so I might have put a comma in a wrong place. Whip up a sqlfiddle and we might test.

Comment: @demonoid The fiddle should have some data you know.

Comment: @demonoid You have NULLs in input you get NULLs on output, you never mentioned that before or how you want NULLs to be handled, so what's the problem? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22f7f/1

Comment: Well, for branch 2, course 2 there is 1 value. Also if for branch 2, course 2  everything is null you can handle it as returning 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89903/discussion-between-demonoid-and-jakub-kania).